# Does uninstalling Raspberry Pi GUI speed up the device when used via SSH?

Tags: linux, user-interface, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I'm using my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B as a small and super simple LAMP development server. However it is on the edge of acceptable performance, especially when it comes to bulk copying or handling large MySQL databases.

The set-up:

1. The Pi has no display attached
2. I access the device via SSH and WinSCP
3. I changed the GUI boot behavior via `raspi-config` to command line only

What makes me curious is that whenever I connect to the Pi via the Windows Remote Control tool I still get a GUI.

Therefore I'm wondering whether if there are any negative performance implications or if Raspbian does not load the GUI until explicitly requested from the remote control tool.

If there are negative implications, what configurations should I change? (PS: I like to have a GUI from time to time but I could do without it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the RPi is *very* starved of memory, there will be no performance difference as long as the graphical interface isn't actively being used.

Having said that, I would not try to run a large database on it unless I was using a class 10 card or better and the database configuration was heavily tuned.

Comment: Thank you. Using the Samsung EVO 32 GB, Class 10, which seems to have very good performance. Could you explain what database configurations you would tune?